# subset of R undefined columns

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to use subset to get values from the union of two tables

```
> ans<-subset(table2, select=rownames(table1))
```

But i get the following error:

> Error in [.data.frame(x, r, vars, drop = drop) :    undefined columns selected

Given ***table1***

```
  V2
E  x
F  x
G  x
H  x
```

And ***table2***

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  A  B  C  D  E  F
2  2  5  6  4  6  8
```

I want to obtain:

```
E   F

6   8
```

Comment: `subset(table2, select=intersect(rownames(table1), colnames(table2)))`

Comment: Hello, r2evans, Thank you so much for your help!
> ans
data frame with 0 columns and 2 rows

Comment: You should consider repairing your ```table2``` with ```tbl2 <- table2[-1, ]; names(tbl2) <- unlist(table2[1, ]); tbl2 <- lapply(tbl2, as.integer)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this data:

```
table1 <- structure(list(V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "x", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("E", 
"F", "G", "H"))

structure(list(X1 = c("A", "2"), X2 = c("B", "5"), X3 = c("C", 
"6"), X4 = c("D", "4"), X5 = c("E", "6"), X6 = c("F", "8")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Note: This does not work if the data structure is factors. I assembled table2 with:

```
table2 <- data.frame(rbind(as.character(LETTERS[1:6]), c(2, 5, 6, 4, 6, 8)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

So, then this works:

```
ans <- table2[, as.character(table2[1, ]) %in% rownames(table1)]

ans
```

Comment: Hello, markhogue,Thank you so much for your great help! It works!